# js update keyframe property VANISHED

Tags: javascript

This is the strangest bug that I have ever met. blowed my mind.

```js
function render_element(styles, el) {
  for (const [kk, vv] of Object.entries(styles)) {
el.style[kk] = vv;
  }
}

function capitalize(s){
return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
}

function swap(node1, node2) {
const afterNode2 = node2.nextElementSibling;
const parent = node2.parentNode;
node1.replaceWith(node2);
parent.insertBefore(node1, afterNode2);
}

function sortOnKeys(dict) {
var sorted = [];
for(var key in dict) {
    sorted[sorted.length] = key;
}
sorted.sort();
var tempDict = {};
for(var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    tempDict[sorted[i]] = dict[sorted[i]];
}
return tempDict;
}

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

// round to 2 decimal places
const rit = val => Math.round(val * 100) / 100;

const unique = function(prefix){
if(!unique.cache)unique.cache = {};
if(unique.cache[prefix] == null)unique.cache[prefix] = 0;
unique.cache[prefix]++;
return prefix + unique.cache[prefix].toString();
}

// [1, 3], 3 -> [1, 2, 3]
const linespace = (tar, den) => Array.from({
  length: den
}, (x, i) => tar[0] + i * (tar[1] - tar[0]) / (den - 1));

const isInt = value => !isNaN(value) && (function(x) {
  return (x | 0) === x;
})(parseFloat(value));

// degree to radians
function d2r(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

// radians to degree
function r2d(rad) {
  return rad * 180 / Math.PI;
}

// theta = atan m
// convert y = kx + b to y = r x
// archive cartesian to polar and force domain to [0, 2pi] by
// regarding the line start from center and goes to one of the four quadrants
function get_rad(x, y) {
  var rad = Math.atan(y / x);
  if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
rad = Math.PI + rad;
  } else if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
rad = Math.PI + rad;
  } else if (x > 0 && y < 0) {
rad = 2 * Math.PI + rad;
  }
  return rad;
}

// pass in one point and a radians to ratate
// return a rotated dot
function rotate_by_origin(pt, rt) {
  var phi = get_rad(pt.x, pt.y) + rt;
  var r = (pt.x ** 2 + pt.y ** 2) ** 0.5;
  if (phi > 2 * Math.PI) {
phi -= 2 * Math.PI;
  }
  if (0 < phi < Math.PI * 0.5) {
return {
  x: Math.cos(phi) * r,
  y: Math.sin(phi) * r
};
  } else if (Math.PI * 0.5 < phi < Math.PI) {
phi -= 0.5 * Math.PI;
return {
  x: -Math.cos(phi) * r,
  y: Math.sin(phi) * r
};
  } else if (Math.PI < phi < Math.PI * (2 / 3)) {
phi -= Math.PI;
return {
  x: -Math.cos(phi) * r,
  y: -Math.sin(phi) * r
};
  } else {
phi -= (2 / 3) * Math.PI;
return {
  x: Math.cos(phi) * r,
  y: -Math.sin(phi) * r
};
  }
}

// pass in two dots and one radians
// return a dot
// rotate pt by ori with rt radians
function rotate_one(ori, pt, rt) {
  var bk = {
x: pt.x - ori.x,
y: pt.y - ori.y
  };
  var rbk = rotate_by_origin(bk, rt);
  return {
x: rbk.x + ori.x,
y: rbk.y + ori.y
  };
}

// pass in side, center, mouse
function nPolyDots(n, cen, pt) {
  var inde = 2 * Math.PI / n;
  var cont = [];
  cont.push(pt);
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
cont.push(rotate_one(cen, pt, i * inde));
  }
  return cont;
}

class XY{
constructor(s, x, y){
    this.s = s;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.concat = this.concat.bind(this);
    this.calcX = this.calcX.bind(this);
    this.calcY = this.calcY.bind(this);
    this.parse = this.parse.bind(this);
}
calcX(func){this.x = func(this.x);return this}
calcY(func){this.y = func(this.y);return this}
concat(){return new XY(this.s, this.x, this.y)}
parse(){return this.s + rit(this.x).toString() + ' ' + rit(this.y).toString()}
}

// let xy = new XY('L', 10, 12);
// console.log(xy.addX(10).addY(-10).mulX(2));

class ML{
constructor(d){
    if(d){
        // sep always parsed to space
        let sep = d.includes(',') ? ',' : ' ';
        this.d = d;
        this.zflag = d.includes('Z');
        this.xys = d.split('L').map(st=>isInt(st[0]) ? new XY("L", ...st.split(sep).map(dd=>rit(parseFloat(dd)))) : new XY('M', ...st.split(sep).map((dd, ii)=>ii === 0 ? rit(parseFloat(dd.substring(1))) : rit(parseFloat(dd)))));
        this.calcX = this.calcX.bind(this);
        this.calcY = this.calcY.bind(this);
        this.concat = this.concat.bind(this);
        this.parse = this.parse.bind(this);
    }
}

calcX(func){this.xys.forEach(xy=>xy.calcX(func));return this}
calcY(func){this.xys.forEach(xy=>xy.calcY(func));return this}

concat(){
    let ml = new ML();
    ml.xys = this.xys.map(xy=>xy.concat());
    ml.zflag = this.zflag;
    return ml;
}

get length(){return this.xys.length;}

parse(){
    return this.xys.map(xy=>xy.parse()).join(' ') + (this.zflag ? 'Z' : '');
}
}

class Vector{
constructor(
    parent_el,
    id,
    width,
    height,
){
    this.parent_el = parent_el;
    this.id = id;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    this.widgets = [];
    this.parent_el.innerHTML += `<svg viewBox="0 0 ${width} ${height}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>`
    this.el = this.parent_el.lastChild;
    this.viewBox = this.viewBox.bind(this);
    this.addPath = this.addPath.bind(this);
}

viewBox(dx, dy){
    this.width += dx; 
    this.height += dy; 
    this.el.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${this.width} ${this.height}`)
    return this;
}

addPath(widget){
    this.widgets.push(widget);
    widget.init(this);
    return widget;
}
}

class Path{
constructor(
    id, 
    str,
    width,
    height,
){
    this.id = id;
    this.str = str;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
    this.fit = this.fit.bind(this);
    this.frontMost = this.frontMost.bind(this);
    this.front = this.front.bind(this);
    this.backMost = this.backMost.bind(this);
    this.back = this.back.bind(this);

    this.animsvg = [];
    this.animcss = [];
}

get el(){return this.host.el.getElementById(this.id)}

init(vector){
    this.host = vector; // Vector instance (SVG)
    this.host.el.innerHTML += this.str;
}

fit(){
    this.host.viewBox(-this.host.width + this.width, -this.host.height + this.height);
}

async frontMost(ms){
    if(ms){await delay(ms)}
    let path_el = this.el;
    this.host.el.removeChild(path_el);
    this.host.el.appendChild(path_el);
    return this;
}

async front(ms){
    if(ms){await delay(ms)}
    let kids = [];
    for(let ii = 0; ii < this.host.el.children.length; ii++){
        kids.push(this.host.el.children[ii]);
    }
    let path_el = this.el;
    let ind = kids.indexOf(path_el);
    this.host.el.removeChild(path_el);
    this.host.el.insertBefore(path_el, kids[ind + 2]);
    return this;
}

async back(ms){
    if(ms){await delay(ms)}
    let kids = [];
    for(let ii = 0; ii < this.host.el.children.length; ii++){
        kids.push(this.host.el.children[ii]);
    }
    let path_el = this.el;
    let ind = kids.indexOf(path_el);
    this.host.el.removeChild(path_el);
    this.host.el.insertBefore(path_el, kids[ind - 1]);
    return this;
}

async backMost(ms){
    if(ms){await delay(ms)}
    let path_el = this.el;
    this.host.el.removeChild(path_el);
    this.host.el.insertBefore(path_el, this.host.el.children[0]);
    return this;
}

static star(
    id, 
    radius, 
    deg, // rotate degree
    padding, 
    fill, 
    stroke,
    strokeWidth,
){
    // star is composed by two 5 side polygons
    // wheares sin54 r = sin18 R
    let r_out = radius;
    let r_in = Math.sin(d2r(18)) / Math.sin(d2r(54)) * r_out;
    let center = {x: r_out, y: r_out};
    let s_out_pre_r = {x: r_out, y: 2 * r_out - padding};
    let s_out = rotate_one(center, s_out_pre_r, d2r(180 + deg));
    let s_in_pre_r = {x: r_out, y: r_out + r_in};
    let s_in = rotate_one(center, s_in_pre_r, d2r(216 + deg));
    let p_out = nPolyDots(5, center, s_out);
    let p_in = nPolyDots(5, center, s_in);
    let c_out = 0;
    let c_in = 0;
    let pts = [];
    for(let ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++){
        if(ii % 2 === 0){
            pts.push({x: rit(p_out[c_out].x), y: rit(p_out[c_out].y)});
            c_out++;
        }else{
            pts.push({x: rit(p_in[c_in].x), y: rit(p_in[c_in].y)});
            c_in++;
        }
    }
    let path = Array.from(pts, (ii, cc)=>(cc === 0 ? "M" : "L") + ii.x.toString() + ',' + ii.y.toString()).join(' ') + 'Z';
    let ra = radius * 2;
    return new Path(
        id, 
        `<path id=${id} d="${path}" fill="${fill}" stroke="${stroke}" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="${strokeWidth}"></path>`,
        ra,
        ra,
    );
}

addAnimStatic(anim){
    this.animcss.push(anim);
    anim.init(this);
    return anim;
}
}

class Keyframe{
constructor(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.cache = [];
    this.tag = document.createElement('style');
    // bind
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
    this.replace = this.replace.bind(this);
}

add(di){
    this.cache.push(di);
    document.head.appendChild(this.tag);
    return ()=>this.cache.indexOf(di);      
}

pop(ind){
    if(ind == null)return null;
    this.cache.splice(ind, 1);
    this.push();
    return this.cache.length;
}

replace(ind, di){
    this.cache[ind] = di;
}

push(){
    let di = {};
    this.cache.forEach(keyframe=>{
        for(const [time, css] of Object.entries(keyframe)){
            if(!di[time]){
                di[time] = Object.assign({}, css);
            }else{
                for(const [prop, val] of Object.entries(css)){
                    if(Object.keys(di[time]).includes(prop)){
                        if(prop === 'transform'){
                            di[time][prop] += ' ' + css[prop];
                        }else{
                            di[time][prop] = css[prop];
                        }
                    }else{
                        di[time][prop] = css[prop];
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    });     
    // parse a string
    let st = '@keyframes ' + this.id + ' {';
    for(const [time, css] of Object.entries(di)){
        st += time.toString() + '%{';
        for(const [prop, val] of Object.entries(css)){
            st += prop + ': ' + val + ';';
        }
        st += '}';
    }
    st += '}';
    this.tag.innerHTML = st;
}

remove(){
    document.head.removeChild(this.tag);
}
}

// use a panel to integrite all
class AnimStatic{
constructor(
    name, // func name
    func, // static animation function
    di, // param to func
    tflag, // bool transform flag
    keyframe,  
    styles,
){
    this.name = name;
    this.func = func;
    this.di = di;
    this.tflag = tflag; 
    this.keyframe = keyframe;
    this.styles = styles;
    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
}

init(path){
    this.host = path;
    if(!this.host.keyframe)this.host.keyframe = new Keyframe(path.id + 'Anim');
    this.ind = this.host.keyframe.add(this.keyframe);
    this.host.keyframe.push();
    render_element(this.styles, path.el);
    if(path.el.style.animation !== ''){
        path.el.style.animation += `, ${this.host.keyframe.id} ${this.di.dur}ms ${this.di.begin}ms ${this.di.timing} ${this.di.count}`;
    }else{
        path.el.style.animation = `${this.host.keyframe.id} ${this.di.dur}ms ${this.di.begin}ms ${this.di.timing} ${this.di.count}`;
    }
}

remove(){
    if(!this.host.keyframe.pop(this.ind())){
        let disp = window.getComputedStyle(this.host.el, null).display;
        this.host.el.style.animation = 'none';
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.host.el.style.animation = disp;
        }, 0);
    }else{
        let anim = this.host.el.style.animation;
        let disp = window.getComputedStyle(this.host.el, null).display;
        this.host.el.style.animation = 'none';
        this.host.el.style.display = 'none';
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.host.el.style.animation = anim;
            this.host.el.style.display = disp;
        }, 0);
    }
}

update(di){
    console.log(['update', this.host]);
    Object.assign(this.di, di);
    // parse a new keyframe
    Object.assign(this, this.func(this.di));
    this.host.keyframe.replace(this.ind(), this.keyframe);
    this.host.keyframe.push();
    let anim = this.host.el.style.animation;
    this.host.el.style.animation = 'none';
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.host.el.style.animation = anim;
    }, 0);
    console.log(['aftupdate', this.host]);
}

static wrapper(prop, values, percents){
    let di = {};
    percents.forEach((pc, ii)=>{
        di[pc] = {[prop]: values[ii]};
    });
    return di;
}

/*
interface{
    begin: Number,
    dur: Number, 
    values: any,
    percents: Array, 
    timing: String, default to 'ease-in-out', 
    count: String, default to 'indefinite',
    styles: Object, default to {}
}
*/

static opacity(di){
    return new AnimStatic(
        'opacity', 
        AnimStatic.opacity, 
        di, 
        false, 
        AnimStatic.wrapper('opacity', di.values, di.percents), 
        di.styles,
    )
}

// transform frame
static translate(di){
    return new AnimStatic(
        'translate', 
        AnimStatic.translate, 
        di, 
        true, 
        AnimStatic.wrapper('transform', di.values.map(val=>`translate(${val[0]}, ${val[1]})`), di.percents),
        di.styles,
    )
}

static scale(di){
    return new AnimStatic(
        'scale', 
        AnimStatic.scale, 
        di,  
        true, 
        AnimStatic.wrapper('transform', di.values.map(val=>`scale(${val[0]}, ${val[1]})`), di.percents),
        di.styles,
    )
}

static rotate(di){
    return new AnimStatic(
        'rotate', 
        AnimStatic.rotate,
        di, 
        true, 
        AnimStatic.wrapper('transform', di.values.map(val=>`rotate(${val}deg)`), di.percents),
        di.styles,
    )
}

static skew(di){
    return new AnimStatic(
        'skew', 
        AnimStatic.skew, 
        di,  
        true, 
        AnimStatic.wrapper('transform', di.values.map(val=>`skew(${val}deg)`), di.percents),
        di.styles,
    )
}
}

let svg = new Vector(
document.body,
'light',
200,
200,
);
svg.viewBox(400, 400);

let star = svg.addPath(
Path.star(
    'star',
    150,
    0,
    10,
    'gray',
    'lightgreen',
    15,
)
);

let a1 = star.addAnimStatic(
AnimStatic.translate({
    begin: 100, 
    dur: 1000, 
    values: [['0', '0'], ['200px', '200px'], ['200px', '0']], 
    percents: [0, 50, 100],
    timing: 'ease-in-out',
    count: 'infinite',
    styles: {},
})
);

setTimeout(()=>{
a1.update({
    values: [['0', '0'], ['200px', '200px'], ['0', '200px']], 
});
setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(['sec', a1.host]);
    a1.update({
        values: [['0', '0'], ['200px', '0'], ['200px', '200px']], 
    });
    console.log(['aftsec', a1.host]);
}, 900);
}, 900);
```

```css
svg{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

body{
position: fixed;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

I am trying to apply css keyframe animation to elements by javascript.

1. `addAnimStatic` will create a `<style>` tag into `<header>` and the name of the animation will be added to the widget.
2. `update` will overwrite the keyframe.

here is the part that went wrong without any logic. please take a look at the end of the script and pay close attention to the console, I am trying to update the animation twice, the first one works, but the second.

before the beginning of second animation, I logged `a1.host` which the result is shown. however, in the next line, when it got to `update` function, the `host` property magically disappeared.

which there is absolutely no conduction in between. When the scope jumped from `setTimeout` to `AnimateStatic.update`, the property `host` just vanished.

I will be so glad if you can give me a hand.

---

after one day of trying, I still have no idea why the property just vanished.

---

#### Minimum working example

[codepen](https://codepen.io/MessizQin/pen/ZEKmKBg)

---

In the original design I was meant to use `click` to trigger the animation update, it does not work as well, the same error `undefined variable this.host` reported.

Comment: 600 lines of code? Please provide the *minimal* code needed to reproduce the issue. Not sure anyone will want to dig into this script. BTW, that is not a *variable*, but a *property*.

Comment: Just a guess but there could be a problem with the way you are using setTimeout. Take a look at; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout
(The "this" problem, Nested timeouts)

Comment: @trincot the minimum working example is added. it uses a div instead of involving sophisticated SVG calculation. Please checkout the codepen, only about 300 lines.

Comment: This is NOT a minimal reproducible example at all. Remove everything that is not needed to reproduce the issue. Knowing where the issue is myself, I can tell that a true [MCVE] should contain only the AnimStatic class, which itself should only have its constructor and its `init`, `translate` and `update` methods, which should all contain only `this.host = ...`, `return new ...`  and `Object.assign(this, ...` respectively. (hint: you return a new instance but never call its `init` method.

Comment: Also, not to stop you in your work, but do you know there is already a full API right inside your browser to do what you are doing? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API

Comment: @Kaiido `init` is called before `Object.assign(this, ...`, which in update `this.func` return a new `AnimStatic` instance **without** host property. The only place where `host` is assigned is `init`, but I don't understand how it turns to `null` somewhere. I also tried to store the `host` to a variable at the start of `update` and assign it to `this` at the end, did not work as well, which at the start I got null, it just went missing when the scope is changed.

Comment: agree with the above, this is not remotely "minimal". Not only are you going to put people off trying to help when they have to understand a few hundred lines of code rather than a few dozen (I speak as exactly one who could not be bothered to comb through such code, I like helping people here but am not going to spend hours of my time unpaid!) - more importantly, by thinking through what is and what isn't needed to reproduce your problem, you get much closer to understanding the issue yourself. Even if you can't fully fix it, you make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: having said that, huge kudos to @Kaiido for (so it seems, and I have no reason to doubt (s)he's correct) trawling through this and finding the real issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please next time spend time removing everything that is not necessary in order to reproduce the error, it takes time, but it will definitely help you find your issues.

Doing so we end up in this situation:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.getId = this.getId.bind(this);
  }
  init(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
  update() {
    const bar = new Foo();
    Object.assign(this, bar);
  }
}

const instance = new Foo();
instance.init("foo");
console.log(instance.getId()); // "foo"
instance.update();
console.log(instance.getId()); // undefined
```

Now it's a lot easier to see what happens:

When extending our original *foo* instance with the new *bar* instance, *bar*'s bound `getId` method got assigned to *foo*, but this method is still bound to the intermediary *bar* object.

So in your case, the `update()` method is the one of the instance returned by `translate`, whose `init` is never called and thus which doesn't have a `host` property.

It seems you don't really need to bind these methods, so don't.

```js
function render_element(styles, el) {
  for (const [kk, vv] of Object.entries(styles)) {
    el.style[kk] = vv;
  }
}

function capitalize(s) {
  return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
}

function swap(node1, node2) {
  const afterNode2 = node2.nextElementSibling;
  const parent = node2.parentNode;
  node1.replaceWith(node2);
  parent.insertBefore(node1, afterNode2);
}

function sortOnKeys(dict) {
  var sorted = [];
  for (var key in dict) {
    sorted[sorted.length] = key;
  }
  sorted.sort();
  var tempDict = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    tempDict[sorted[i]] = dict[sorted[i]];
  }
  return tempDict;
}

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

// round to 2 decimal places
const rit = val => Math.round(val * 100) / 100;

const unique = function(prefix) {
  if (!unique.cache) unique.cache = {};
  if (unique.cache[prefix] == null) unique.cache[prefix] = 0;
  unique.cache[prefix]++;
  return prefix + unique.cache[prefix].toString();
}

// [1, 3], 3 -> [1, 2, 3]
const linespace = (tar, den) => Array.from({
  length: den
}, (x, i) => tar[0] + i * (tar[1] - tar[0]) / (den - 1));

const isInt = value => !isNaN(value) && (function(x) {
  return (x | 0) === x;
})(parseFloat(value));

// degree to radians
function d2r(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

// radians to degree
function r2d(rad) {
  return rad * 180 / Math.PI;
}

// theta = atan m
// convert y = kx + b to y = r x
// archive cartesian to polar and force domain to [0, 2pi] by
// regarding the line start from center and goes to one of the four quadrants
function get_rad(x, y) {
  var rad = Math.atan(y / x);
  if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
    rad = Math.PI + rad;
  } else if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
    rad = Math.PI + rad;
  } else if (x > 0 && y < 0) {
    rad = 2 * Math.PI + rad;
  }
  return rad;
}

// pass in one point and a radians to ratate
// return a rotated dot
function rotate_by_origin(pt, rt) {
  var phi = get_rad(pt.x, pt.y) + rt;
  var r = (pt.x ** 2 + pt.y ** 2) ** 0.5;
  if (phi > 2 * Math.PI) {
    phi -= 2 * Math.PI;
  }
  if (0 < phi < Math.PI * 0.5) {
    return {
      x: Math.cos(phi) * r,
      y: Math.sin(phi) * r
    };
  } else if (Math.PI * 0.5 < phi < Math.PI) {
    phi -= 0.5 * Math.PI;
    return {
      x: -Math.cos(phi) * r,
      y: Math.sin(phi) * r
    };
  } else if (Math.PI < phi < Math.PI * (2 / 3)) {
    phi -= Math.PI;
    return {
      x: -Math.cos(phi) * r,
      y: -Math.sin(phi) * r
    };
  } else {
    phi -= (2 / 3) * Math.PI;
    return {
      x: Math.cos(phi) * r,
      y: -Math.sin(phi) * r
    };
  }
}

// pass in two dots and one radians
// return a dot
// rotate pt by ori with rt radians
function rotate_one(ori, pt, rt) {
  var bk = {
    x: pt.x - ori.x,
    y: pt.y - ori.y
  };
  var rbk = rotate_by_origin(bk, rt);
  return {
    x: rbk.x + ori.x,
    y: rbk.y + ori.y
  };
}

// pass in side, center, mouse
function nPolyDots(n, cen, pt) {
  var inde = 2 * Math.PI / n;
  var cont = [];
  cont.push(pt);
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    cont.push(rotate_one(cen, pt, i * inde));
  }
  return cont;
}

class XY {
  constructor(s, x, y) {
    this.s = s;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
// DO NOT BIND
//    this.concat = this.concat.bind(this);
//    this.calcX = this.calcX.bind(this);
//    this.calcY = this.calcY.bind(this);
//    this.parse = this.parse.bind(this);
  }
  calcX(func) {
    this.x = func(this.x);
    return this
  }
  calcY(func) {
    this.y = func(this.y);
    return this
  }
  concat() {
    return new XY(this.s, this.x, this.y)
  }
  parse() {
    return this.s + rit(this.x).toString() + ' ' + rit(this.y).toString()
  }
}

// let xy = new XY('L', 10, 12);
// console.log(xy.addX(10).addY(-10).mulX(2));

class ML {
  constructor(d) {
    if (d) {
      // sep always parsed to space
      let sep = d.includes(',') ? ',' : ' ';
      this.d = d;
      this.zflag = d.includes('Z');
      this.xys = d.split('L').map(st => isInt(st[0]) ? new XY("L", ...st.split(sep).map(dd => rit(parseFloat(dd)))) : new XY('M', ...st.split(sep).map((dd, ii) => ii === 0 ? rit(parseFloat(dd.substring(1))) : rit(parseFloat(dd)))));
// DO NOT BIND
//      this.calcX = this.calcX.bind(this);
//      this.calcY = this.calcY.bind(this);
//      this.concat = this.concat.bind(this);
//      this.parse = this.parse.bind(this);
    }
  }

  calcX(func) {
    this.xys.forEach(xy => xy.calcX(func));
    return this
  }
  calcY(func) {
    this.xys.forEach(xy => xy.calcY(func));
    return this
  }

  concat() {
    let ml = new ML();
    ml.xys = this.xys.map(xy => xy.concat());
    ml.zflag = this.zflag;
    return ml;
  }

  get length() {
    return this.xys.length;
  }

  parse() {
    return this.xys.map(xy => xy.parse()).join(' ') + (this.zflag ? 'Z' : '');
  }
}

class Vector {
  constructor(
    parent_el,
    id,
    width,
    height,
  ) {
    this.parent_el = parent_el;
    this.id = id;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    this.widgets = [];
    this.parent_el.innerHTML += `<svg viewBox="0 0 ${width} ${height}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>`
    this.el = this.parent_el.lastChild;
// DO NOT BIND    
//    this.viewBox = this.viewBox.bind(this);
//    this.addPath = this.addPath.bind(this);
  }

  viewBox(dx, dy) {
    this.width += dx;
    this.height += dy;
    this.el.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${this.width} ${this.height}`)
    return this;
  }

  addPath(widget) {
    this.widgets.push(widget);
    widget.init(this);
    return widget;
  }
}

class Path {
  constructor(
    id,
    str,
    width,
    height,
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.str = str;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
// DO NOT BIND    
//    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
//    this.fit = this.fit.bind(this);
//    this.frontMost = this.frontMost.bind(this);
//    this.front = this.front.bind(this);
//    this.backMost = this.backMost.bind(this);
//    this.back = this.back.bind(this);

    this.animsvg = [];
    this.animcss = [];
  }

  get el() {
    return this.host.el.getElementById(this.id)
  }

  init(vector) {
    this.host = vector; // Vector instance (SVG)
    this.host.el.innerHTML += this.str;
  }

  fit() {
    this.host.viewBox(-this.host.width + this.width, -this.host.height + this.height);
  }

  async frontMost(ms) {
    if (ms) {
      await delay(ms)
    }
    let path_el = this.el;
    this.host.el.removeChild(path_el);
    this.host.el.appendChild(path_el);
    return this;
  }

  async front(ms) {
    if (ms) {
      await delay(ms)
    }
    let kids = [];
    for (let ii = 0; ii < this.host.el.children.length; ii++) {
      kids.push(this.host.el.children[ii]);
    }
    let path_el = this.el;
    let ind = kids.indexOf(path_el);
    this.host.el.removeChild(path_el);
    this.host.el.insertBefore(path_el, kids[ind + 2]);
    return this;
  }

  async back(ms) {
    if (ms) {
      await delay(ms)
    }
    let kids = [];
    for (let ii = 0; ii < this.host.el.children.length; ii++) {
      kids.push(this.host.el.children[ii]);
    }
    let path_el = this.el;
    let ind = kids.indexOf(path_el);
    this.host.el.removeChild(path_el);
    this.host.el.insertBefore(path_el, kids[ind - 1]);
    return this;
  }

  async backMost(ms) {
    if (ms) {
      await delay(ms)
    }
    let path_el = this.el;
    this.host.el.removeChild(path_el);
    this.host.el.insertBefore(path_el, this.host.el.children[0]);
    return this;
  }

  static star(
    id,
    radius,
    deg, // rotate degree
    padding,
    fill,
    stroke,
    strokeWidth,
  ) {
    // star is composed by two 5 side polygons
    // wheares sin54 r = sin18 R
    let r_out = radius;
    let r_in = Math.sin(d2r(18)) / Math.sin(d2r(54)) * r_out;
    let center = {
      x: r_out,
      y: r_out
    };
    let s_out_pre_r = {
      x: r_out,
      y: 2 * r_out - padding
    };
    let s_out = rotate_one(center, s_out_pre_r, d2r(180 + deg));
    let s_in_pre_r = {
      x: r_out,
      y: r_out + r_in
    };
    let s_in = rotate_one(center, s_in_pre_r, d2r(216 + deg));
    let p_out = nPolyDots(5, center, s_out);
    let p_in = nPolyDots(5, center, s_in);
    let c_out = 0;
    let c_in = 0;
    let pts = [];
    for (let ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
      if (ii % 2 === 0) {
        pts.push({
          x: rit(p_out[c_out].x),
          y: rit(p_out[c_out].y)
        });
        c_out++;
      } else {
        pts.push({
          x: rit(p_in[c_in].x),
          y: rit(p_in[c_in].y)
        });
        c_in++;
      }
    }
    let path = Array.from(pts, (ii, cc) => (cc === 0 ? "M" : "L") + ii.x.toString() + ',' + ii.y.toString()).join(' ') + 'Z';
    let ra = radius * 2;
    return new Path(
      id,
      `<path id=${id} d="${path}" fill="${fill}" stroke="${stroke}" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="${strokeWidth}"></path>`,
      ra,
      ra,
    );
  }

  addAnimStatic(anim) {
    this.animcss.push(anim);
    anim.init(this);
    return anim;
  }
}

class Keyframe {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.cache = [];
    this.tag = document.createElement('style');
// DO NOT BIND
//    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
//    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
//    this.replace = this.replace.bind(this);
  }

  add(di) {
    this.cache.push(di);
    document.head.appendChild(this.tag);
    return () => this.cache.indexOf(di);
  }

  pop(ind) {
    if (ind == null) return null;
    this.cache.splice(ind, 1);
    this.push();
    return this.cache.length;
  }

  replace(ind, di) {
    this.cache[ind] = di;
  }

  push() {
    let di = {};
    this.cache.forEach(keyframe => {
      for (const [time, css] of Object.entries(keyframe)) {
        if (!di[time]) {
          di[time] = Object.assign({}, css);
        } else {
          for (const [prop, val] of Object.entries(css)) {
            if (Object.keys(di[time]).includes(prop)) {
              if (prop === 'transform') {
                di[time][prop] += ' ' + css[prop];
              } else {
                di[time][prop] = css[prop];
              }
            } else {
              di[time][prop] = css[prop];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
    // parse a string
    let st = '@keyframes ' + this.id + ' {';
    for (const [time, css] of Object.entries(di)) {
      st += time.toString() + '%{';
      for (const [prop, val] of Object.entries(css)) {
        st += prop + ': ' + val + ';';
      }
      st += '}';
    }
    st += '}';
    this.tag.innerHTML = st;
  }

  remove() {
    document.head.removeChild(this.tag);
  }
}

// use a panel to integrite all
class AnimStatic {
  constructor(
    name, // func name
    func, // static animation function
    di, // param to func
    tflag, // bool transform flag
    keyframe,
    styles,
  ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.func = func;
    this.di = di;
    this.tflag = tflag;
    this.keyframe = keyframe;
    this.styles = styles;
// DO NOT BIND
//    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
//    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
//    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }

  init(path) {
    this.host = path;
    if (!this.host.keyframe) this.host.keyframe = new Keyframe(path.id + 'Anim');
    this.ind = this.host.keyframe.add(this.keyframe);
    this.host.keyframe.push();
    render_element(this.styles, path.el);
    if (path.el.style.animation !== '') {
      path.el.style.animation += `, ${this.host.keyframe.id} ${this.di.dur}ms ${this.di.begin}ms ${this.di.timing} ${this.di.count}`;
    } else {
      path.el.style.animation = `${this.host.keyframe.id} ${this.di.dur}ms ${this.di.begin}ms ${this.di.timing} ${this.di.count}`;
    }
  }

  remove() {
    if (!this.host.keyframe.pop(this.ind())) {
      let disp = window.getComputedStyle(this.host.el, null).display;
      this.host.el.style.animation = 'none';
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.host.el.style.animation = disp;
      }, 0);
    } else {
      let anim = this.host.el.style.animation;
      let disp = window.getComputedStyle(this.host.el, null).display;
      this.host.el.style.animation = 'none';
      this.host.el.style.display = 'none';
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.host.el.style.animation = anim;
        this.host.el.style.display = disp;
      }, 0);
    }
  }

  update(di) {
    console.log(['update', !!this.host]);
    Object.assign(this.di, di);
    // parse a new keyframe
    Object.assign(this, this.func(this.di));
    this.host.keyframe.replace(this.ind(), this.keyframe);
    this.host.keyframe.push();
    let anim = this.host.el.style.animation;
    this.host.el.style.animation = 'none';
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.host.el.style.animation = anim;
    }, 0);
    console.log(['aftupdate', !!this.host]);
  }

  static wrapper(prop, values, percents) {
    let di = {};
    percents.forEach((pc, ii) => {
      di[pc] = {
        [prop]: values[ii]
      };
    });
    return di;
  }

  /*
  interface{
    begin: Number,
    dur: Number, 
    values: any,
    percents: Array, 
    timing: String, default to 'ease-in-out', 
    count: String, default to 'indefinite',
    styles: Object, default to {}
  }
  */

  static opacity(di) {
    return new AnimStatic(
      'opacity',
      AnimStatic.opacity,
      di,
      false,
      AnimStatic.wrapper('opacity', di.values, di.percents),
      di.styles,
    )
  }

  // transform frame
  static translate(di) {
    return new AnimStatic(
      'translate',
      AnimStatic.translate,
      di,
      true,
      AnimStatic.wrapper('transform', di.values.map(val => `translate(${val[0]}, ${val[1]})`), di.percents),
      di.styles,
    )
  }

  static scale(di) {
    return new AnimStatic(
      'scale',
      AnimStatic.scale,
      di,
      true,
      AnimStatic.wrapper('transform', di.values.map(val => `scale(${val[0]}, ${val[1]})`), di.percents),
      di.styles,
    )
  }

  static rotate(di) {
    return new AnimStatic(
      'rotate',
      AnimStatic.rotate,
      di,
      true,
      AnimStatic.wrapper('transform', di.values.map(val => `rotate(${val}deg)`), di.percents),
      di.styles,
    )
  }

  static skew(di) {
    return new AnimStatic(
      'skew',
      AnimStatic.skew,
      di,
      true,
      AnimStatic.wrapper('transform', di.values.map(val => `skew(${val}deg)`), di.percents),
      di.styles,
    )
  }
}

let svg = new Vector(
  document.body,
  'light',
  200,
  200,
);
svg.viewBox(400, 400);

let star = svg.addPath(
  Path.star(
    'star',
    150,
    0,
    10,
    'gray',
    'lightgreen',
    15,
  )
);

let a1 = star.addAnimStatic(
  AnimStatic.translate({
    begin: 100,
    dur: 1000,
    values: [
      ['0', '0'],
      ['200px', '200px'],
      ['200px', '0']
    ],
    percents: [0, 50, 100],
    timing: 'ease-in-out',
    count: 'infinite',
    styles: {},
  })
);

setTimeout(() => {
  a1.update({
    values: [
      ['0', '0'],
      ['200px', '200px'],
      ['0', '200px']
    ],
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(['sec', !!a1.host]);
    a1.update({
      values: [
        ['0', '0'],
        ['200px', '0'],
        ['200px', '200px']
      ],
    });
    console.log(['aftsec', !!a1.host]);
  }, 900);
}, 900);
```

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

body {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Also, note that to do what you are trying to do, there is already [a full API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) built-in your browser.

Comment: cheers, `Object.assign(this, ...` I did not notice `update` is overwritten in constructor which the function is bonded to the new instance since, and the new instance does not have `host` property although the old instance does.